# Save in VTK old format 3.0

Tags: python, save, vtk

I want to create vtk file with mesh(I use vtk 9)
The vtk should have :

```
# vtk DataFile Version 3.0
POINTS 
POLYGONS 
NORMALS
```

I create a 3d cube object

```
cube1 = vtk.vtkCubeSource()
cube1.SetXLength(6)
cube1.SetYLength(10)
cube1.SetZLength(4)
cube1.SetCenter(0,2,0)
cube1.Update()
```

How do I save it in required format?
I tried this

```
 writer = vtk.vtkPolyDataWriter()
 writer.SetInputData(cube1.GetOutput())
 writer.SetFileName('cube1.vtk')
 writer.Update()
```

I got format 5.1 but I need the old one.If there is any way to get old format?(Except using old version of vtk)

Comment: An alternative is to save the file "manually" using VTK [simple legacy format](https://vtk.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/file-formats.pdf)

Comment: Or try modern `vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VTK does not allow to select an old format, so VTK 9 can only write legacy files in version 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

In VTK 9 there is support to write in older format 4.2.

```
writer = vtk.vtkPolyDataWriter()
writer.SetFileVersion(42)
...
```

This will write in older format.